# how to build nested array from other nested array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I have array where each element is array of sql columns.
One element of MAIN array looks like this:

```
Array(

    [type] => water
    [id] => KK
    [animalName] => "josip"
    [key] => 123
    [key2] => 2
    [alive] => true
    [name] => "Lilly"
    [key] => 1
    [big] => false
)
```

now i need to build nested array which looks like this:

```
array(

    [type] => water
    [id] => KK
    ["animals"] => array(
                 [animalName] => "josip"
                 [key] => 123
                 [key2] => 1.5
                 [alive] => true
                 ["babies" => array(
                              [name] => "jimmy"
                              [key] => 1
                              [big] => false
                            )
               )
```

as long as type == type in previous element of MAIN array i need to add more animals, so

```
array(

    [type] => water
    [id] => KK
                 ["animals"] => array(
                   [animalName] => "rom"
                   [key] => 213
                   [key2] => 5423
                   [alive] => true
                   ["babies" => array(
                              [name] => "julia"
                              [key] => 199
                              [big] => false
                            )
               )
                 ["animals"] => array(
                   [key] => 123123111
                   [key2] => 123213
                   [alive] => true
                   [name] => "tom"
                   ["babies" => array(
                              [name] => "robert"
                              [key] => 1123
                              [big] => false
                            )
               )
```

i have built an algorithm but it was really complex and unoptimal so im looking for as simple as possible solution, any ideas?

the point is to get json with structure:

```
{
   "type":"water",
   "id":"KK",
   "animals":[
      {
         "AnimalName":"crocodile",
         "key":1,
         "key2":1.1,
         "alive":true,
         "babies":[
            {
               "name":"jimmy",
               "Key":123,
               "big":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "AnimalName":"fish",
         "key":22,
         "key2":1.5,
         "alive":true,
         "babies":[
            {
               "name":"lilly",
               "key2":5,
               "big":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "type":"land",
   "id":"LL",
   "animals":[
      {
         "AnimalName":"lion",
         "key":1,
         "key2":1.1,
         "alive":true,
         "babies":[
            {
               "name":"jimmy",
               "Key":123,
               "big":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "AnimalName":"dog",
         "key":22,
         "key2":1.5,
         "alive":true,
         "babies":[
            {
               "name":"lilly",
               "key2":5,
               "big":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

as long as type == type in previous element of main array add more animals, if type differs from previus add next element to root array with other type and add other animals.

Im sorry if its messy a little

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: i have built three arrays and then put them together, in for each loop i added index and depends on index  i added values to arrays but it doesnt work really good

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will helpful for you..

```
$array = array(

        'type' => 'water',
        'id' => 'KK',
        'animalName' => "josip",
        'key' => 123,
        'key2' => 2,
        'alive' => 'true',
        'name' => "Lilly",
        'key3' => 1,
        'big' => 'false'
    );
    $resulArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == 'animalName' || $key == 'key' || $key == 'key2' ||  $key == 'alive') {
            $resulArray['animals'][$key] = $value;
        }
        else if ($key == 'name' || $key == 'key3' || $key == 'big') {
            $resulArray['animals']['babies'][$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $resulArray[$key] = $value;
        }    
    }

    // return array
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resulArray);

    // return json 
    $resulJson = json_encode($resulArray);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resulJson);
```